# Python Datafram groupby KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have created a dataframe of fantasy baseball players, collecting stats from a few different sites. Most of my issues I have been able to resolve with some searching and troubleshooting, but this one has got me stumped. For my final sheet I am trying to bring everything together, and group the stats from duplicate playerid's and take the mean of those stats so it's not showing duplicate rows (same player ID has different stats in each column based on where the projections came from. When I do a print of the all_players df I get this output:

```
             PA      R    HR    RBI    SB  ...    W   ERA  WHIP  SVHD  Position
playerid                                   ...                                 
607208      NaN  107.0  24.0   91.0  34.0  ...  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN
592450    677.0  112.0  44.0  107.0  12.0  ...  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN
592450      NaN  106.0  45.0  109.0   9.0  ...  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN
592450    649.0  112.6  42.9  103.6  12.0  ...  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN
592450    652.0  102.0  41.0  109.0  11.0  ...  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN
```

As you can see players 592450 is duplicated and I want to group it into one row based on the playerid and take the mean of the other columns so I am trying to do this:

`final_sheet = (all_players.groupby('playerid').mean().sort_values('Rating', ascending=False))`

in doing so I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\FantasyBaseballProjections\venv\projections.py", line 233, in <module>
    final_sheet = (all_players.groupby('playerid')
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\FantasyBaseballProjections\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 10093, in merge
    return merge(
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\FantasyBaseballProjections\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 110, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\FantasyBaseballProjections\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 703, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\FantasyBaseballProjections\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1162, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\FantasyBaseballProjections\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1850, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'playerid'
```

checking for indexes in my all_players dataframe I ran this:
`print(all_players.index.names)`
with an output of:
`['playerid']`

I guess I will also add that the all_players dataframe came from the merge of the all_batters and all_pitchers dataframes where I did this:
`all_players = all.batters.merge(all_pitchers, how='outer', on=['playerid', 'System', 'Rating'])`

There is some additional code that goes in with the final_sheet but in the end I want something like this:

```
Rank    ADP     Name    Position    Rating  Notes   xwOBA19     cnrv19  PA  R   ...     SB  AVG     K/9     IP  K   W   ERA     WHIP    SVHD    playerid
0   1   1.7     Ronald Acuna Jr.    OF  11.38   Med Upside  0.386 (22)  34.48 (18)  247     41  ...     12  0.284                               18401
1   2   1.6     Christian Yelich    OF  11.32   Stable  0.420 (3)   58.67 (2)   241     39  ...     8   0.306                               11477
2   3   6.1     Gerrit Cole     SP  10.24   Med Upside  0.238 (9)   -52.14 (2)          ...             12.48   76  105     6   3.17    1.03    0   13125
```

Comment: are you certain you have a column named "playerid"?  and if it does exist, is it part of a multi-level index on the dataframe?

Comment: I took a look again at the columns from all_players and playerid isn't listed, so I'm assuming it is part of a multi-level index after looking that up (I am still fairly new to python) ... is there a way to go from here with that?

Comment: Common reason for a KeyError from groupby method is that the specified column name does not exist. Try instead of `playerid` use the correct name in your group by.  To check if multi-level exists (less likely)  (2 rows) `index_names = all_players.index.names` 
`print('multi-level index names:', index_names)`

Comment: ```index_names = all_players.index.names
print('multi-level index names:', index_names)```
`multi-level index names: ['playerid']`

Answer (score 1):

As `playerid` is your index, you have to use `level='playerid'` as parameter of `groupby`:

```
all_players.groupby(level='playerid')
```

So the full code should be:

```
final_sheet = (all_players.groupby(level='playerid').mean().sort_values('Rating', ascending=False))
```

Comment: Tried that with the same results